# Get Passwords of wifi network on iDevices

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, network-protocols

Is there any ways to find out the Wifi Passwords saved on my iPhone / iPad without Jailbreaking the device?

If anyone suggests me it would be very goood :)

Comment: Why can't you find them out the same way you did when you first entered them?

Comment: it would be better if you would tell why you want to achieve it then we could tell alternatives if present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Not At All ! Strictly No!** You cannot do that in any way on a non-jailbroken device. I think its not even possible on Jailbroken devices as well(Not sure).

Comment: On Jailbroken devices we can do. Thats why I am asking.!!